# Error logging in with PayPal payments

Tags: php

I am using PayPal to process payments on my site, direct the user to the paypal checkout site, then redirect them back to the success page on my site, but I am having issues when one is directed to the paypal landing page. It won't accept valid paypal username and or passwords to login to complete the transaction. Has anyone had this issue before? Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the html form code I have:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"          target="_top"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="ZHGKEN49VB9SG">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Here is the link if it helps: http://tunesparker.com/members

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.

Comment: I changed the question so you can see the code and the page in action. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are directing your users to the PayPal Sandbox. Valid users accounts on PayPal are not necessarily valid accounts on the Sandbox. Switch to the live version of PayPal.